# @Jsoncomponent does not get recognized springboot

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to deserialise an a JSON input using a class that is annotated with `@JsonComponent`. However, even though I manually register this class, it is still not invoked when I call the endpoint with the input. I use `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`  for generating `controllers` and `aspectj` for compile-time weaving. Can this interfere with the objects being recognised?

Note: The same setup works in a different poc application that I made but not this one. The main difference I see is the code generation. Hence I'm wondering if using the `open-api-generation` interferes with the `Deserializer` being recognised during the call to the `Controller`

```
@JsonComponent
public class UserDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<User> {

        @Override
        public User deserialize (JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext
        deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        log.info("***********INVOKED***************");
        TreeNode treeNode = jsonParser.getCodec().readTree(jsonParser);
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        //Some logic here
    }

}
```

Config class has

```
@Bean
public Module userDeserializer() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(User.class, new UserDeserializer());
    return module;
}
```